# Using NSolve to get a solution for Bessel-related functions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I want to get a solution of a equation using NSolve.

$BesselI[1,x]/(x*BesselI[0,x])=0.2$

So I plugged this equation to NSolve:

```
NSolve[BesselI[1,x]/(x*BesselI[0,x])==0.2, x]
```

But when I use this, the Mathematica gives the same expression. I know that this equation has such a solution from plot:

[image]

Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

Any helps will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bound the value for `x`

```
Solve[{BesselI[1, x]/(x*BesselI[0, x]) == 1/5, -5 < x < 5}, x]

(* {{x -> Root[{(-5) BesselI[1, #] + 
     BesselI[
       0, #] #& , -4.38411711031472304526702680222165674734`18.}]}, {x -> 
   Root[{(-5) BesselI[1, #] + BesselI[0, #] #& , 
     4.38411711031472304526702680222165674734`18.}]}} *)

NSolve[{BesselI[1, x]/(x*BesselI[0, x]) == 1/5, -5 < x < 5}, x]

(* {{x -> -4.38412}, {x -> 4.38412}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reason that the code doesn't work when I don't bound the value of x?

Comment: By default Mathematica assumes that all variables are complex. It doesn't know how to solve the equation in the complex plane. Even if you specify that `x` is real, it still doesn't know how to solve the equation. Restricting the range makes the problem simpler and enables Mathematica to find the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Often the solver of `NMinimize`is more robust and calculates one solution

```
NMinimize[{1, BesselI[1, x]/(x*BesselI[0, x]) == 0.2}, x]
(*{1., {x -> -4.38412}}*)
```

without restriction.

Second solution follows to

```
NMinimize[{1, BesselI[1, x]/(x*BesselI[0, x]) == 0.2,x>0}, x]
(*{1., {x -> 4.38412}}*)
```

Comment: Or `NArgMin[{(BesselI[1, x]/(x*BesselI[0, x]) - 1/5)^2, #}, x] & /@ {x < 0, x > 0}`